# Google analytics visualization dataTable 'Avg. Time on Page' format as 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have formatted the Google analytics API response "ga:avgTimeOnPage" as like "00:00:00" using below format.

1. Assigned the query as like below.

```js
 var referral_pages_Config = {
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions, ga:bounceRate, ga:avgTimeOnPage',
      dimensions: 'ga:fullReferrer',
      'max-results': 6,
      sort: '-ga:sessions',
      'output': 'dataTable'
    },
    chart: {
      options: {
     width: '100%'
      }
    }
   };
```

2. Formatted the  "ga:avgTimeOnPage" response as like below using, "avg_time_val.toHHMMSS();". Its worked fine till last month. But, now its not updating the format as like I changed about. So, as per my research, its not allow to change the display format.

```js
  referral_pages.on('success', function(response) {

   response.dataTable.cols[0].label = 'Page';
   response.dataTable.cols[1].label = 'Page Views';
   response.dataTable.cols[2].label = 'Bounce Rate';
   response.dataTable.cols[3].label = 'Avg. Time on Page';



   var referral_pages = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.dataTable);

   var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
                 fractionDigits: 2,
                 suffix:'%'
                 });
   var formatter_visiter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
                 pattern:'###,###'
                 });
   formatter_visiter.format(referral_pages, 1);
   formatter.format(referral_pages, 2);


   // Format Time as per the User-end
     for (var k = 0, profile; profile = response.dataTable.rows[k]; k++) {
    //alert(profile.c[3].v);
    var avg_time_val = profile.c[3].v;
    var formatt_time_val = avg_time_val.toHHMMSS();
    profile.c[3].v = formatt_time_val;
     }

   var referral_pages_table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('referral_pages_container'));
   referral_pages_table.draw(referral_pages);
  });
```

If we changed the format, its displaying as NAN. Anyone guide me the solution to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this problem because in the `referral_pages` DataTable, 3rd column is originally of type 'number'. But when you are formatting using `toHHMMSS` and replacing the value, it is becoming a 'string'. Because of this datatype conflict, you are seeing NaN. Unfortunately, there is no way to convert the datatype for a column of DataTable once it has been created.

The solution for your problem is to create a DataView. Check the following code, I have tried and tested it - it works.

```
referral_pages.on('success', function(response) {

response.dataTable.cols[0].label = 'Page';
response.dataTable.cols[1].label = 'Page Views';
response.dataTable.cols[2].label = 'Bounce Rate';
response.dataTable.cols[3].label = 'Avg. Time on Page';

var referral_pages = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.dataTable);

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 2,
    suffix:'%'
});
var formatter_visiter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern:'#,##,###'
});
formatter_visiter.format(referral_pages, 1);
formatter.format(referral_pages, 2);

var columns = [];

for (var i = 0; i < referral_pages.getNumberOfColumns() - 1; i++) {
    columns.push(i);
}

columns.push({
    type: 'string',
    label: referral_pages.getColumnLabel(3),
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        var val = dt.getValue(row, 3);
        return (val != '' && val != null) ? val.toHHMMSS() : null;
    }
});

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(referral_pages);
view.setColumns(columns);

var referral_pages_table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('timeline'));
referral_pages_table.draw(view);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Its working great! Thanks Sasank Mukkamala!